# How to pass a NSArray to a POST using MKNetworkKit

Tags: ios, json, mknetworkkit

MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithPath:@"thestore/services/storeservice.svc/getfavorites" 
                                                params:fetchedObjects
                                                httpMethod:@"POST"];

The fetechedObjects is an array. I can loop through the array to get the values I need to put into the POST request body

```
[
 {
     "id": 9222,
    "latitude": 19.7897,
    "longitude": -64.0208
 },
 {
     "id": 7832,
     "latitude": 79.7713,
     "longitude": -44.1084
 }
]
```

But I can't figure out how to use the MKNetworkOperation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to try is to set the `postDataEncoding` property of the operation to `MKNKPostDataEncodingTypeJSON`. This *should* cause the array to be serialized and set as the request body.

**However**, `MKNetworkKit` doesn't really support array values for the `params` parameter; it expects a dictionary. If you hit the wrong code path, it could crash because it expects a dictionary where you've provided an array.

Comment: Yes it is set to MKNKPostDataEncodingType JSON. OK so I'm thinking I'll need to extend the network kit to have an  NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
   
  MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithPath:@"thestore/services/storeservice.svc/getfavorites" 
                                            params:fetchedObjects
                                        httpMethod:@"POST"];

Answer (score 2):

This should probably help you.

```
  [op setCustomPostDataEncodingHandler:^NSString *(NSArray *listOfItems) {

    return [listOfItems description];

  } forType:@"text/json"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by sending array (products) as list :

> NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:products
>                                                              options:0 // non-pretty printing
>                                                                error:nil];
>               ;
>               [params setObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:@"list"];